# How many characters to do frequency analysis?

Tags: cryptanalysis, frequency-analysis

Is there any study that has looked into what is the minimum number of ciphertext characters one needs to have to do a reliable frequency analysis?
It would be nice to know the evolution of the accuracy of the analysis as the number of characters considered increases, but I haven't found any well done study.

Comment: Welcome, and an excellent opening...